# AngularJS pause $location change

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to run a transition before a `$location` change, in vanilla JS I can choose not to process the `onhashchange` or `pushstate` update til I'm ready, but how do I achieve this in AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at $locationChangeStart (there are a bunch of other events that you might want to look into as well: $locationChangeSuccess, $includeContentLoaded, $viewContentLoaded, $routeChangeStart, $routeChangeError, $routeUpdate, $routeChangeSuccess.

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {
    // Do things here and then you can use event.preventDefault() 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Furthermore, I guess I'd restart the process by calling `$routes.reload()`.